# Checking if a directory name is all numbers c++

Tags: c++

Hello I'm trying to get a list of all the processes inside `/proc/` but for this, I need to check if the name of the directory is a number, after some work I find this function to do the job:

```
if(std::all_of(dirp->d_name, dirp->d_name + std::strlen(dirp->d_name), [](char c){return std::isdigit(c);}))
```

What I don't understand is why I have to add `dirp->d_name + std::strlen(dirp->d_name)` as the second argument.

Wouldn't be enough just passing the length given by `std::strlen(dirp->d_name)`?

Comment: Both arguments require iterators to define an open and closed range.  That's how most STL algorithms work.

Comment: You can read the [documentation for `std::all_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) and see what arguments it requires. Unless you're actually asking why `all_of` is implemented that way?

Comment: Note that STL algorithms that do take a number to denote the number of elements are usually named with a *_n* suffix.  For example `std::generate_n`, `std::fill_n`, etc.  So if there was an algorithm for `all_of` that takes a number as a second argument, it would probably be named `std::all_of_n`.